# show that the length of the curve $\alpha$ tends to infinity when $N \to \infty$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The following example shows that for any reasonable definition, the length of a curve $C ^0$ in a range defined closed may be unlimited. Let $ \alpha: [0,1] \to \mathbb {R}^2 $ given by
$$\alpha (t) =\left( t, \sin \frac {\pi} {t}\right) $$ if $ t\neq 0 $, and $\alpha (0) = (0.0) $. Shows geometrically that the arc length of the curve portion corresponding to
$ \frac {1} {n +1} \leq t \leq \frac {1} {n} $
is at least $\frac{2}{n + \frac{1}{2}}$. Use this to show that the curve length in the range $\frac {1} {N} \leq t \leq 1$ is greater than $ 2 \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac {1}{n +1} $, thus tending to infinity when $ N \to \infty $.

Comment: Take a look at the second coordinate of the curve in the indicated interval. What is it at the endpoints? And in the middle?

Comment: I'm in the first part ... I'm not managing to get the shortest length of the curve is $ \frac {2}{n + \frac{1}{2}} $ ... the idea I had was to build a polygonal considering the points $ \alpha\left(\frac{2}{2n+2}\right), \ \alpha\left(\frac{2}{2n +1}\right), \ \alpha \left(\frac{2}{2n}\right)$ learned that $\frac{2}{2n +1}$ is a critical point and $\alpha \left(\frac{2}{2n}\right)=\alpha \left(\frac{2}{2n+2}\right)=0$.

Comment: corrected .. thank you

Comment: Well, you can compute the second coordinate of $\alpha(2/(2n+1))$ easily enough … On second thought, that means the estimate given in the problem, while true, is vastly weaker than it could be. Should it have been $\alpha(t)=(t,t\sin(\pi/t))$, perhaps.

Comment: yes... $\alpha \left( \frac{2}{2n+1}\right)=+-1$ but it does not matter ....... I want to know is why it is the lowest LENGTH in $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Thanks...

Comment: Critical points are OK, I guess. But think of it this way. As $t$ goes from $1/k$ to $1/(k+1/2)$, the curve travels a distance $\gt 1$.

Comment: I also think.,.then in $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}$ would >2

Comment: A side remark: the curve $\alpha$ is not continuous at $t=0$. A better example would be $\alpha(t) = (t,t \sin(1/t^2))$.

Comment: but it is $C^0$...